# using c++ wrapper in c# .NET project

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using the C++ wrapper in this link:
https://github.com/TekRTSA/RSA_API

In order to use a driver written in C++ inside C# project.
When I publish/release my C# project it doesn't work on other computers without Visual C++.

Is there any way that I can publish my project on computers that don't have the visual C++? Or is there any software package like .NET that I can use in order to make it work?

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing on 'other' computers?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd the redistribuable might be needed by the library you're using, in which case there's not much you can do. Just make sure you let your user know they the the VC++ redist and it should be fine, it's a fairly common reditribuable

Comment: Thanks, This is the Error: Could not load file or assembly 'APILibrary.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Alternatively, you could statically link your unmanaged C++ library so that it has no dependencies to any external DLLs.

Comment: You also need to distribute APILIbrary.dll to your customers computers too.

Answer (score 1):

With .NET applications you need to make sure customers have a version of .NET that matches what you compiled your application with.

With (Microsoft) C++ applications that depend on the C Runtime, you need to make sure customers have a version of the Visual C++ Redistributables that matches what you compiled your application with. Do a google search for 'visual c++ redistributable' and you will see lots of suggestions on what to look for.

Comment: I found this redistributable: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads But It looks like it for the visual studio and my app didn't work on computers without the visual studio. Is there any other redistributable that can run without VS?

Comment: Also make sure the C++ dll is compiled as Release build, debug builds cannot be redistributed without VS installed (at least not in a supported way)

Comment: You have to know what version of the visual c++ compiler you are compiling against. And then find the matching visual c++ redist.